# Resize downloaded image from URL using SDWebImage from YouTube JSON EDITED

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm downloading thumbnail images from youtube JSON web service using SDWebImage, in order to set them in a table view cell. The problem is that the download image is 120x90, too big for my needs , as I want to fit it in a UIImageView of 75x75. While the images are cached in the placeholder, they look correct, but once cache is finished, they look in the 120x90 ratio size. I tried setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, but it doesn't work, so I don't know how to solve this issue.

```
NSString *path= [thumbnail valueForKey:@"sqDefault"];

        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

        CALayer * l = [cell.imageView layer];

        [l setMasksToBounds:YES];

        [l setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

Many thanks

EDITED:

I have set content mode in the custom cell extended class:

```
newsCell.m

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self.Image   setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

    }


    return self;
}
```

And here is the cell creation code:

multimedia.m

```
 newsCell *cell = [self.tableView 
                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"news"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[newsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"news"];
        }
```

The issue is that if (cell == nil) is never called because first statement is creating cell, so initWithStyle is not called and content mode is not set, but if I delete first statement, cell is not created. I don't know how to manage it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these two options and see which better fits your needs:

```
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
UIViewContentModeAspectFill
```

If these don't work, I am guessing it is because the UITableViewCell is setting the contentMode on the UIImageView -- in this case you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell that contains a UIImageView with the proper contentMode set. Then you can use your custom UITableViewCell subclass in your UITableView.

Comment: They don't work, but Xcode claims to use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit instead of UIViewContentModeAspectFit. Thanks

Comment: I added some info that might help you out.

Comment: Michael, I followed your instructions, I have edited the question, so I have a problem to init custom cell. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set custom size of your table image view in its custom cell class

```
    - (void)layoutSubviews {  
    [super layoutSubviews];  
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,40,32.5);  
    float limgW =  self.imageView.image.size.width;  
    if(limgW > 0) {  
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(55,self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,self.textLabel.frame.size.width,self.textLabel.frame.size.height);  
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(55,self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);  
    }  
}
```

For more details [please refer this link](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2011/11/sdwebimage-fixed-width-cell-images/)